# Why does the peak of a mountain appear bright on Radar images?

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, topography, radar, sentinel-1

Why does the top of a `mountain` appear bright on a `SAR` (`radar`) image.
I know that the `peak` of a mountain is subject to a `layover` effect, thus appearing closer on the `radar image` than the bottom part of the mountain. And, that the back part of a mountain is dark (`shadow`) because it is not reached by `radar`'s radiations.

The only reason I see that makes the top of a mountain look brighter than the bottom part is because the `slope` of the mountain is narrower on `slant range` compared to its real dimensions on `ground range`. This implies that `backscatter return` from many objects is returned inside the same cell (more `intensity`). But I'm not sure if that is really the exact reason.

See `Sentinel-1` `SAR` image of mountain (to understand what I'm talking about):

[image: <code>Sentinel-1</code> <code>SAR</code> image of sahara mountains]

Comment: I think you answered your own question " slopes facing the radar will be foreshortened and ones facing away from it will be lengthened from their horizontal(map) dimensions. The former will therefore be brightened and the latter dimmed. " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_aperture_radar#Image_appearance

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks for your answer. So it will have a higher intensity because the `backscatter` return is compressed in a small area (slope) on the radar image, right?

Comment: @Mapperz The multiple bounce between `ground` and `mountain slope` could also cause an increase of the `backscatter` return. Don't really know if this could be the reason though.

Comment: Since you are looking at intensity images you allready answered your own question. If the signal hits a slope that is almost perpendicular to it more of it will be scattered back to the satellite therefore increasing the intensity of the measured return signal.

Comment: @Kersten Thanks. But I thought that `layover` is an extreme example of the `foreshorting` at least according to what I'm reading on this book `Ulaby - Microwave Radar and Radiometric Remote Sensing p726`. `Foreshorting` cause the `fore slope` of a mountain to have a length shorter than it's real length, and `layover` cause the `peak` to appear closer to the radar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably also getting more backscatter because there is bare rock at the summit instead of vegetation. Vegetation holds moisture, which would absorb microwaves rather than backscattering.

Besides, the `foreshortening` which affects the fore slope increases its intensity (having more backscatter returned into the same cell yield more intensity.

Comment: I know that `wet vegetation` appears brighter than `dry vegetation` and that `dry soil` usually appear black on `radar images`, so why would `rock` have a higher backscatter than `vegetation`? Is it because it has a `rough` surface?   Besides, this image was taken in the sahara (`arid climate`); no `vegetation` exist there, and rock will definitely be dry too.

Comment: Waves penetrate less solid/hard surfaces easier than more solid. (Trees & Vegetation vs. Rocks). Less penetration equals more reflection, which results in more backscatter.

Comment: You're right, I think I should just add to the answer above (@Will McInnes) the effect of `foreshortening` and `layover` on the increase of the intensity (having more backscatter returned into the same cell yield more intensity).